# Use dollar sign prefixed property names (obj.$myprop) throughout AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'll have to work on a dataset with a given structure that contains elements with dollar signs in their property names: `foo$bar` oder even in the beginning like `$bar`. There will be *no* double dollar sign in the beginning of a property name like `$$forbidden`.

I am aware that `$$`-properties are dropped/ignored on several places throughout Angular and the use of `$`-prefixed names is discouraged for dependency injection.

Is it safe to use these property names in my data-model, though? Which parts of AngularJS may be critical? How much pain am I to expect from future AngularJS updates?

Comment: _"I am aware that $$-properties are dropped/ignored on several places throughout Angular"_ That's new to me. I haven't heard of that, before. What I'd suggest: Just give it a try. If it doesn't work, _then_ ask a question.

Comment: Only very specific functions, like `angular.toJson`, will drop `$$` values for your convenience. It won't arbitrarily go through your data and change it. You should be fine in regular use. I concur that you should go build something and worry about it when you encounter an edge case.

Answer (score 2):

First, I dont think you may face some real issues with single `$` right now.

But this is not good, so if i.e. you are getting dataset from some API call - just add functions to trasform reqest/response to remove all dollars and transformResponse to add them where needed.